# Theme suggestions for text on specific block

Tags: theming

I want to have a theme suggestion for field--text-with-summary.html.twig based on block in which it is. I just want to add a css class to it in this specific block. Any idea on how to write the hook function, Please?

Comment: Since this question has something to do with twig, I'm guessing this question is about D8. Am I close?

Comment: Yes you are right. It's about Drupal. Sorry